# Retrieving very old events

Tags: events, nodes, infura

While working with Infura in the past, if I remember correctly, I had troubles with retrieving events from old (non-recent) blocks.

Does the trouble (not only with Infura but with other popular Ethereum nodes) still exist?

In fact, I want to be able to retrieve events from *very* old blocks, even 100 years old (in the future).

Is it better to store such very old data on-chain? (It won't take much storage because it's just one storage slot per user.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what was the case in the past but nowadays Infura seems to be pretty reliable when it comes to retrieving old Logs produced by events.

In fact, with the script below you will be able to retrieve the only [Log](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x218b632d932371478d1ae5a01620ebab1a2030f9dad6f8fba4a044ea6335a57e#eventlog)(and probably the first one ever created) in block [52029](https://etherscan.io/block/52029), which was mined on **Aug-08-2015**

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/' + your_project_id));

web3.eth.getPastLogs({
    fromBlock : 0,
    toBlock : 52029
}).then(console.log);
```

To **answer your second question** i will quote something from the [solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#events):

> Events are inheritable members of contracts. When you call them, they cause the arguments to be stored in the transaction’s log - a special data structure in the blockchain. These logs are associated with the address of the contract, are incorporated into the blockchain, and stay there as long as a block is accessible (forever as of now, but this might change with Serenity). The Log and its event data is not accessible from within contracts (not even from the contract that created them).

As you can see, for the time being you can access all past logs, but this might change with Serenity. So for such long-term data, your safest option is to store them on-chain.